# GridDB Installation Fails or Performs Suboptimally - Suspecting Insufficient Memory Allocation

Tags: installation, windows-subsystem-for-linux, griddb

Hello Stack Overflow community,

I'm encountering challenges with the installation of GridDB, and I suspect that insufficient memory allocation might be the root cause.

```
Securing of memory may have failed.
```

And this is the Error code:
`CM_NO_MEMORY`

I'm currently utilizing a WSL machine, and my GridDB version is "5.1.0-39692 CE.”

I tried to close any application running in the background and restart my device.

My question is:
What are the recommended memory settings for GridDB, and how can I adjust them during installation?